# java easymock: Can I invoke another method when a mock is called?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, easymock

I want to execute some code when a particular mock method is invoked.

```
mock = EasyMock.createMock(ConListener.class);

// Record n Replay
mock.Connected();
mock.DataSent();
EasyMock.replay(mock);


sock = createCon(addr, mock)

// I want the send to be called only after the mock's Connected() is invoked.
sock.send("data");
```

Is there any approach where I can achieve to perform an Invoke action when a mock is called?

```
mock.Connected().Invoke () //something like this?
```

What i have so far is,

```
mock = EasyMock.createMock(ConListener.class);

// Record n Replay
mock.Connected();
mock.DataSent();
EasyMock.replay(mock);

CompletableFuture<Void> connected = new CompletableFuture<Void>();
sock = createCon(addr, new ConListener() {
   public void Connected() {
      mock.Connected();
      connected.complete(null);
   }

   public void DataSent() { mock.DataSent(); }
});
connected.get()
sock.send("data");
```

Wanted to check if there is a better and clean way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the `addDelegate` to solve my problem.. Not so clear and intuitive but slightly better than my previous approach.

```
interface ConListener {
   void Connected();
   void DataSent(int size);
}

// Having it as a class, so that I can only add stub codes,
// for a particular method and leave the rest.

class TestListener implements ConListener {
   void Connected() {Assert.fail("")}
   void DataSent(int size) {Assert.fail("")}
}


@Test
public void SomeTest() {
   CompletableFuture<Void> connected = new CompletableFuture<Void>();
   mock = EasyMock.createMock(ConListener.class);

   // Record
   mock.Connected();
   EasyMock.expectLastCall().andDelegateTo(new TestListener() {
      public void Connected() {
        connected.complete(null);
      }
   });
  EasyMock.expectLastCall().times(1); // This cannot come before adding delegates. Why?
  EasyMock.replay(mock);

  // Test
  sock = createCon(addr, mock/*using actual mock*/);
  connected.get(timeout, unit);
  sock.send(blahblah);  

}
```